how to update a data table at runtime
I'm bound to use a data table to work with common UI: common action widget but I have this key binding system and I need to update the data table to be able to change the icons
I know a lot of you think that data tables are static and there is no way to alter them in any way and that's what I was thinking but there are people out there that managed to do it like this one or this and the list goes on and on meaning it's possible I just don't know how yet.
thanks<3
EDIT: I'm aiming to change the content of data table like edit rows or delete and add new ones

Please clarify your question, a lot makes sense in isolation, but together they make no sense. What/ how do you want to update on the data table? The type? The amount of columns? What has keybinding to do with data tables? Or icons?

@Zibelas I just edit it hope it makes more sense now
